# Are there [good/optimal] parallel comparison sorts?

Tags: dc.parallel-comp, sorting

Comparing each pair of elements and sorting according to

[[number less than] minus [number greater than]] is a parallel comparison

sorting algorithm with a depth of $1$ comparison and $O\left(n^2\right)$ total comparisons.

By the [AKS network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network#Optimal_sorting), there is a parallel comparison sorting algorithm with

a depth of $O(\log(n))$ comparisons and $O(n\cdot \log(n))$ total comparisons.

1.
Are there any parallel comparsion sorts with a depth of

$o(\log(n))$ comparisons and $o\left(n^2\right)$ total comparisons?

2.
Are there any parallel comparison sorts with a depth

of $1$ comparison and $O(n\cdot \log(n))$ total comparisons?

Comment: As side note, sorting is $\mathsf{TC^0}$-complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(answering my own question)

1. $\:$ Yes

2. $\:$ No

Reference:

Tight Comparison Bounds On The Complexity Of Parallel Sorting

by Yossi Azar , Uzi Vishkin (1987)

publisher: Courant Institute of Mathematical Sciences, New York University

retrieved from http://archive.org/details/tightcomparisonb00azar (June 17, 2012)

Comment: Could you give a more complete reference (authors, conference/journal, date, URL, etc.)?

Comment: Done. $\:$ (Well, I think that's good enough.) $\;\;$

Answer (score 0):

Please help me understand the model.  I think it is equivalent to the following:

There is an array $A$ contained within a comparison oracle $O$ which you can send any list of pairs $[(i_1, j_1), \ldots, (i_n, j_n)]$ and which responds with a list of booleans $[b_1, \ldots, b_n]$ such that $b_k = 1 \iff A[i_k] > A[j_k]$, i.e. if the $k$'th pair represents an inversion.

A sorting algorithm is *correct* if it outputs $i_1, \ldots, i_n$ such that querying $O$ with $[(i_1, i_2), (i_2, i_3), \ldots, (i_{n-1}, i_n)]$ produces $[0, \ldots, 0]$, i.e. the output is sorted.

The performance of such an algorithm is measured by how many queries it performs to the oracle (depth) and the total number of pairs submitted to the oracle (the number of comparisons).

Your question is about the existence of thus defined *correct* sorting algorithms which satisfy various performance bounds.

Is this correct?

Sorting networks are thus a special case where each element may only occur once in each submitted batch of comparisons, as I understand it.  Lifting this restriction is then the reason you can beat the performance of the best sorting networks.  Agreed?

Comment: I hope you'll find this non-post in this non-forum to be a valuable non-contribution ;-)